# calc() always works with width, not with height?

Tags: html, css

I just tried to make a div vertically centered on a 100vh page.

The div is 84px high, so I made:

```
margin-top: calc(50% - 42px);
```

But it seems like the browser always takes the width of the outer div, not the height of the outer div (100vh). How can I use the percent of the height, not the div?

Comment: If you want 50% of viewport height(?) - then use `50vh` ...?

Answer (score 2):

> But it seems like the browser always takes the width of the outer div

Yes. See [the specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties) which says:

> The percentage is calculated with respect to the width of the generated box's containing block. Note that this is true for 'margin-top' and 'margin-bottom' as well.

---

> How can I use the percent of the height

You can't, at least not with plain CSS.

You could use JavaScript if you really need to compute the values at run time.

Since you know the height (you specified that as `100vh` explicitly) then you can use that value.

```
margin-top: calc(50vh - 42px);
```

If you don't want to repeat yourself, then you could use a preprocessor, such as SASS, which would let you store `100vh` in a variable.

Answer (score 1):

You code is failing because margins are calculated against the width of the actual element, no matter which ones. When you said `margin-top: 50%`, it means "50% of the width of this element".

Since you know that the height of the containing element is `100vh` and you want 50% of that, just use `50vh` instead of `50%.`